# BootStrap Switch added with javaScript doesn't fire events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-switch

**EDITED, go below**

I have a table and it has a row click event for each row. The problem is that I've added a switch in the last column ("BootstrapSwitch") and that switch doesn't trigger neither state change or click event because the row click event overlaps it. I know the event works because it does if I place the switch in any other place.

Is there anyway to have the row event in all the row but one column?

```
// Switch event
$('[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',  function(event, state) {
  console.log(this); // DOM element
  console.log(event); // jQuery event
  console.log(state); // true | false
});

// row click
$(document).on('click','.rowDev', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // more code
});
```

**EDIT**

The answer provided should help me but I noticed another problem. Firing event problem. Appended switches to the table with JScript and the initialization maybe don't work, because any of the switches added dynamically work, just those I add manually on .html

This is the row I add to the table

```
"<td><input class='make-switch' type='checkbox' name='my-checkbox' "+ (!anyUnattendedAlert?"checked ":"")+"data-on-color='success' data-off-color='danger' data-on-text='Si' data-off-text='No'>" +
                                    "</td>"+
```

and when all rows are added

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

also tryed to initialize each row I add.
I've been trying in others tables I had without row event and still not firing the switch event (event provided in comments below).

Still dont know how to add those switches and initalize them to work.

P.D:css and js works because switches added manually trigger events.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the full code of the click handler please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by calling `stopPropagation()` on the `click` event which fires on the Bootstrap Switch control. This will stop the event bubbling up the DOM and firing on the parent `.rowDev`:

```
$('[name="my-checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note that you can also join the two event handlers together in one `on()` call if you prefer:

```
$('[name="my-checkbox"]').on({
  'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch': function(e, state) {
    console.log(this); // DOM element
    console.log(e); // jQuery event
    console.log(state); // true | false
  }, 
  'click': function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, I think that code should be the answer but still not firing the event, noticed another error. Editing question.